# Execute http request sequentially in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, observable

I need to send multiple HTTP PUT request to server sequentially (after the next request is only started after completing the previous request, the number of request is not fixed).
If I use the below source code, all request will be sent

```
 `listURL.forEach(url => {
    const req = new HttpRequest('PUT', url, formData, { reportProgress: true});
    httpClient.request(req).subscribe(event=>{});
  });`
```

Is there anyway to execute the requests sequentially?

Comment: use`setInterval` it will execute frequently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not familiar with rxjs, perhaps you can try the following?

```
let requests = listURL.map(url => new HttpRequest('PUT', url, formData, { reportProgress: true});

function do_seq(i) {
  httpClient.request(requests[i]).subscribe(event => {
   if (i < requests.length - 1) do_seq(i + 1);
  });
 }

do_seq(0);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use async/await with `Promise` to stream line this. Convert the observable to a promise using `toPromise()`

```
async doSomethingAsync() {
    for(let url of listURL) {
        const req = new HttpRequest('PUT', url, formData, { reportProgress: true});
        const result = await httpClient.request<ModelHere>(req).toPromise();
        // do something with result
    }
}
```

For more on async/await see also this excellent answer and scroll to the heading [ES2017+: Promises with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/1260204).

Comment: I still have an issue with your answer, could you put it as a function that returns the last promise  ? Written like this, it can't be re-used easily and need to be copy-pasted. ( I also have removed my previous comments as to not pollute your answer)

Comment: @trichetriche - The op is not very clear on if they want to use the result of each call in the next successive call which is why I originally wrote it like this so they could easily see that they can do something with the result. The `doSomethingAsync` returns a promise though (although it is not currently defined in the method signature as the return type). Maybe I am not understanding what you are asking though?

Comment: Put simply, I'm asking for a return statement :)

Answer (score 3):

use `reduce` and `switchMap` :

```
['url 1', 'url 2'].reduce((acc, curr) => acc.pipe(
  mergeMap(_ => this.mockHttpCall(curr)),
  tap(value => console.log(value)),
), of(undefined)).subscribe(_ => console.log('done !'));
```

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7nvbbz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Have the decency to comment when you downvote please, this solution works as expected.